# Directionality of coil in AC current

Tags: pcb, ac, coil

I'm working on a Faraday's Effect experiment, and I'm providing a AC current to a coil such that the AC magnetic field is formed.

However, for some reason, the results change when I flip the coil around, which I don't see why should happen, as the coil should be symmetrical for AC.

Does anyone have any suggestions on why this might be happening?

---

Edit:

I'm using the coil's magnetic field along with glass inside to change the polarization of an incoming light, and detecting the change of angle via a analyzer and a photodiode light sensor.

By "results", I mean the reading on the photodiode light sensor change by ~1.5 times when the direction is flipped. The change of angle is linearly proportional to the magnetic field, and the glass is isomorphic, so I'm thinking it would be something related to the coil. My circuit is connected via a PCB board.

The proportion of change when I flip the coil is smaller when the AC current I supply to the coil is smaller.

Schematic of the Experiment:

[image]

PCB layout:

[image]

The 3 black, green, red connect to a DC power supply, the two probes are each connected to a picoscope and measure the respective voltages, the thin red/blue wire is connected to the LED, the set of thin yellow wires are connected to the coil, the thick yellow wire at the bottom connects to the photodiode and the signal generator (70 Hz) feeds into the grey box.

Coil has 2200 +- 1 turns, and includes a SF57 glass inside.

Comment: Schematic, PCB layout, pictures, details of the coil, data sheet links to important control chips are likely needed.

Comment: Edited it, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Is the coil mechanically symmetrical inside its case? That is, are you moving the coil to a different position when you flip it? Are you moving any ferrous materials around when you flip it, fixings or terminals on the coil's enclosure, or things you have to move out of the way to move the coil? Is the AC symmetrical, or it is pulse-like, or have even harmonics, or is it riding on a DC bias?

Comment: The only coil asymmetry I can think of is that at one terminal the windings are closer to the glass core, but I can't imagine why that would affect the field. What an interesting problem!

Comment: The coil is symmetric as far as I know, and I'm pretty sure position during flipping it isn't the problem as the same problem arises simply when I swap the two cables connecting the coil to the signal generator. Also, I got the same problem with another setup on a different table.

Comment: Asymmetric AC? Current goes more positive than negative. Try inserting a large capacitance in series with the coil, to restore symmetry.

Comment: I have a seperate connection directly measuring the AC current (before it reaches the coil), and it was quite symmetric - from a 80mA current, there was less than 2mA of DC offset. Could that be enough to affect things by more than 1.5 times?

Comment: what happens when you leave the coil where it is, but switch its AC supply leads over?

Comment: It still changes!

Comment: Well then you have a DC bias in your AC, a small offset sufficient to cause the asymmetry in your experimental results. To answer your question "could 2mA DC be enough to affect things by more than 1.5 times?", apparently, yes. What's the AC amplitude?

Comment: It's around 70mA.